# css Display: grid; não consigo alinhar

Tags: css

Estou aprendendo a usar display:grid;
O que eu quero fazer é que na primeira coluna haja um quadrado azul em cima de um verde e a segunda coluna seja toda vermelha.  O que eu tenho é

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OjQEzK

Html

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="upperLeft">UpperLeft</div>
  <div class="lowerLeft">LowerLeft</div>
  <div class="rightColumn">RightColumn</div>
</div>
```

Css

```
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
}

.upperLeft {
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 1;
  background: blue;
}

.lowerLeft {
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 2;
  background: green;
}

.rightColumn {
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 1/2;
  background: red;
  align-self: strech;
}
```

Comment: Mas qual é o problema que você está tendo?

Comment: Realmente não esta bem explicado.  O problema era que a segunda coluna não extendia por toda coluna direita do grid.  Depois de muito briga descobri que era só modificar no .rightColumn pra ficar grid-row: 1/3;

Answer (score 2):

Olá,

Acho que você está tentando fazer isso:

https://codepen.io/CesarCEARA/pen/RZMogY

Fiz esse exemplo para você, veja se entendeu.

```css
/* style */
.box {
    background-color: #444;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: 150%;
}
/* background color */
.bg-green {
  background-color: green;
}
.bg-red {
  background-color: red;
}
.bg-blue {
  background-color: blue
}

/* grid system */
.wrapper {
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 10px;
}
.a {
    grid-column: 1;
    grid-row: 1;
}
.b {
    grid-column: 1;
    grid-row: 2;
}
.c {
    grid-column: 2;
    grid-row: 1 / 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
 <div class="box bg-blue a">A</div>
 <div class="box bg-green b">B</div>
  <div class="box bg-red c">C</div>
</div>
```

Nota: Me deixe saber se isso lhe ajudou.

Um abraço